# WebStorm/React.js html error

Tags: reactjs

This is my first using of react.js and

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qEaBvoJ.jpg]

Code works in browser but html is highlighting in red how to fix this. I'm using JSX Harmony, Webstorm 11 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put raw HTML/JSX into `render`. If you look at [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render), you'll see that you need to pass a `ReactElement` to `render`.

The easiest way to do that would be to create a simple React class using `React.createClass()`